# How can I plot fitted models with observations when dealing with the ANOVA type of research design in R?

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, regression, data-visualization

I am learning how to apply a multilevel modelling to traditional ANOVA research designs.
I would like to plot fitted regression lines for each treatment using ggplot2. I would like to plot regression lines based on models I fitted, not let ggplot2 to plot since I would like to see how estimations differ based on changing models. I am aware that I can calculate coefficients and slopes by myself, but because the model is relatively complicated, I am looking for ways to plot more easily.

This is the sample code for the type of research design I am dealing with. 
I found that the sjPlot package (http://www.strengejacke.de/sjPlot/sjp.lm/) provides very nice plots, which shows the regression lines for each treatment over each test timing and actual observations on a scatter plot. This is exactly what I would like to make with ggplot.

```
 require(tidyverse)
 require(sjPlot)
 set.seed (100)
 dat <- data_frame(
    participant_id = c(c(1:15), c(1:15)),
    treatment = c(sample (letters [1:3], 15, replace = T), sample (letters [1:3], 15, replace = T)),
    test_timing = c(sample(letters [1:3], 15, replace = T),sample(letters [1:3], 15, replace = T)),
    learning_gain = (runif(30, min = 1, max = 20))
)

fit <- lm (learning_gain ~ treatment * test_timing -1, data = dat)
sjp.lm(fit, type = "pred", 
vars = c("test_timing", "treatment"),facet.grid = F)
```

[image]

Or, something like this:

```
 sjp.lm(fit, type = "pred", 
    vars = c("test_timing", "treatment"),facet.grid = T)
```

[image]

I would really appreciate it if you could teach me how I can make a plot similar to this image using the ggplot2 package. Thank you!

Comment: Just from looking at that plot, I would guess that the `sjPlot` package already uses ggplot. It should be possible to modify the resulting plot using standard ggplot functions like `theme()`, and if you look at the code for `sjp.lm`, you'll get an idea of how the plot is put together.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response, @Marius! That's a great idea! I checked the sjPlot source and figured out that `sjPlot` uses the `ggeffect` package. Although I checked the source of `ggeffect` (i.e., `ggpredict()`), I could not understand exactly how can I replicate because I am a novice R learner. I would still appreciate if I could hear how I can plot this, especially for this traditional treatment effect research design. Thank you.

Comment: Someone else might be able to give a fully worked answer, but for an ANOVA like this, the steps are basically a) Generate a dataframe containing all combinations of levels of the predictors `treatment` and `test_timing` b) Use `predict()` with the fitted model and the new dataframe c) Plot the dataframe with ggplot.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know the procedure. Okay, while waiting for someone to provide a comprehensive way to plot this, I will start learning how to use the `predict()` function. Thank you again. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed, *sjPlot* just calls a function from *ggeffects*. *ggeffects* again just returns a data frame with the marginal effects / predicted values. So you can use this data frame to build your own ggplot-objects, or simply use the `plot()`-function to create a plot (a ggplot-object).

There is a package vignette that describes how to build own plots using ggplot:
https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/vignettes/marginaleffects.html

Furthermore, the help-files (see https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggeffects/ggeffects.pdf) are full of examples on how to to create plots using ggplot. Maybe this helps you?

Here is an example for your specific case, but note that you will not see straight lines, because your variables are categorical:

```
require(tidyverse)
require(ggeffects)
set.seed (100)
dat <- data_frame(
  participant_id = c(c(1:15), c(1:15)),
  treatment = c(sample (letters [1:3], 15, replace = T), sample (letters [1:3], 15, replace = T)),
  test_timing = c(sample(letters [1:3], 15, replace = T),sample(letters [1:3], 15, replace = T)),
  learning_gain = (runif(30, min = 1, max = 20))
)

# fit model
fit <- lm (learning_gain ~ treatment * test_timing -1, data = dat)

# compute marginal effects
me <- ggpredict(fit, c("test_timing", "treatment"))

# see results
me

# A tibble: 9 x 5
      x predicted conf.low conf.high group
  <dbl>     <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <fct>
1  1.00      9.81   -0.472      20.1 a    
2  1.00      9.29    4.15       14.4 b    
3  1.00     13.2     5.95       20.5 c    
4  2.00     14.1     8.93       19.2 a    
5  2.00     11.6     7.00       16.2 b    
6  2.00      7.23   -3.06       17.5 c    
7  3.00     13.7     7.77       19.6 a    
8  3.00     13.5     8.33       18.6 b    
9  3.00     10.9     6.66       15.1 c
```

## Line plot

```
# note that predictors are categorical, so no straight line
ggplot(me, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_line()
```

[image]

## Dot plot

```
# plot dots
ggplot(me, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_point()
```

[image]

## Dot plots with error bars

```
# add CI, need jitter
ggplot(me, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0, position = position_dodge(.2))
```

[image]

## Facets

```
# facets
ggplot(me, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  facet_grid(~group)
```

[image]

## plot()-function from the ggeffects package

```
# the simple way
plot(me)
```

[image]

## Raw Observations

`ggpredict()` returns the raw data as attribute to the return value, so you can also plot the original observations as well:

```
raw <- attr(me, "rawdata")

ggplot(me, aes(x = x, y = predicted, colour = group)) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  geom_errorbar(aes(ymin = conf.low, ymax = conf.high), width = 0, position = position_dodge(.2)) +
  # using jitter for observations here
  geom_jitter(data = raw, mapping = aes(x = x, y = response, colour = group))
```

[image]

Or, also the simple way:

```
plot(me, rawdata = TRUE)
```

[image]

See also `?plot.ggeffects` for the different plot options, for instance, use `jitter = FALSE` to remove the jittering for the raw data points etc...

Comment: Thank you very much, @Daniel! This is very neat!! Those graphs are very pretty and clearly showing the characteristics of the data. I also appreciate that you provided the sample codes, which clearly revealing that what `ggpredict()` does. I will check the link, too. If you would not mind me asking, I am also wondering if we could plot the actual observations on these plots. Thank you!

Comment: I added two examples that show how to plot the raw observations.

Comment: That's exactly what I have been looking for!!! Thank you so much, Daniel. I cannot thank you enough!! I hope you have a great day today!

Answer (score 2):

The `emmeans` package is pretty useful:

```
pr <- emmeans::emmeans(fit, ~treatment * test_timing)
ggplot(summary(pr), 
       aes(test_timing, emmean, color = treatment, ymin = lower.CL, ymax = upper.CL)) +
  geom_pointrange(position = position_dodge(0.2), size = 1)
```

[image]

Comment: I think your model is weird, why would it be a linear relationship from b to c to a?? They are categories, as shown here..

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion, @Axeman. This is a very neat plot! It looks like the CIs plotted with this approach are way wider than the CIs plotted with sjPlot. Do you have any idea on this?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. You are right, the sample data I made up was not nice. What I meant by the categorical test timings are, like ‘pre-test’, ‘immediate post test, and ‘delayed post test’. Somehow sjPlot plotted test timing ‘a’ at the end, which made more confusing.

Comment: I still don't see why they would be linearly related, regardless of order. This seams like the reasonable plot to me. There is `emmeans::emtrends` as well for interactions with continuous variables.

Comment: Come to think of it, since I am dealing with ANOVA type research designs, that's reasonable not to assume the linear relationship. Thank you for clarifying my understanding. `emtrends` seems like another convenient function. I will learn more. One more follow up question: Could I plot actual observations on this plot? Thank you.

Comment: You can add additional `geom` functions, that have `data = dat`. E.g. `+ geom_point(data = dat)`.

Comment: Thank you so much! However, when I added `+geom_point(data = dat)`, I got an error message saying that **Don't know how to automatically pick scale for object of type tbl_df/tbl/data.frame. Defaulting to continuous.
Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (9): x, y, colour, ymin, ymax, data**, and the ggplot did not plot.

Comment: Restarting R, I run the same code, and now I am getting **Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : object 'emmean' not found** ...

Comment: Also, is it possible to draw lines between test timings to indicate the grouping characteristics of treatment type? Thank you.

Comment: The provided `plot` method can produce almost exactly the same thing. See `?plot.emmGrid`

Comment: @rvl I agree, but the spirit of the question was how to make your own, in my interpretation.

Comment: Yes, I am specifically looking for ways to plot with ggplot. Because with ggplot I can change the layout and color, and hopefully I can plot actual observations with estimated values. Thank you.